# Getting Empty {} json response in localhost while empty string on cloud-api

Tags: json, rest, go, amazon-ec2, http-post

I created a rest api (POST) in go and deployed it in AWS. Now, if hit my API on local server, i am getting {} empty json in body which is expected because in my service handler in go i have set success as 200 with {} json body.

```
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    w.Write([]byte("{}")) // send empty json in success response
```

The problem is if I hit the same api deployed on aws cloud, i get 200 with "" i.e. empty string response.

The local server and aws cloud deployed server have exactly same code.

What to be the reasoning behind this behavior? I am perplexed.

---

Below is the quick client code that i wrote in my test file. But even with this code, with localhost I get {} and if I hit my cloud endpoint, i get "" empty string in response body.

```
func Test_dfdf(t *testing.T) {
    post()
}


func post() {
    fmt.Println("2. Performing Http Post...")
    todo := customStruct{
        //
    }


    jsonReq, err := json.Marshal(todo)
    req, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodPost, "https://<rest-endpoint>", bytes.NewBuffer(jsonReq))
    req.Header.Set("Authorization", "Bearer <token>")
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    client := http.Client{}
    res, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    buf.ReadFrom(res.Body)
    newStr := buf.String()

    fmt.Println(newStr)
}
```

Comment: This should not happen. Just to verify i deployed [this](https://play.golang.org/p/Hd-3tOq5Ghd) code to an ec2 instance and the response is as expected. Please share the client code you are trying to verify this with.

Comment: Yeah, thats what frustrating me. Added the client code above. BTW, if I use postman, behavior is same.

Comment: I found the issue. somebody had renamed the pods in yaml except at one place. Due to that, service was mapped to older pod (one that was renamed)